# Unique Computer Login

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a bit of help. I realize there are many threads that explain the difficulties and problems of uniquely identifying a computer as far as piracy preventions and user licenses. This situation is a tad bit different in the fact that users must have an active account to log in and use the software. And this option will only be on a requested basis not for every account.

The issue arises when some of the companies have requested instead of admin accounts, they would like admin locations. I am looking if there a good way to do this, or if this will still have the same issues of changing hardware/ spoofing MAC's.

Some of the machine need uniquely identifiable we will have remote access to, while others we won't.
We run on a .NET platform
The only way to use our software is active log-in.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with other answers but have an additional suggestion:
Every Windows generates unique SID on installation... you can get that via `DirectoryEntry` in the `objectSID` item of `Properties`... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx 
hope this helps a bit...

**EDIT - getting MachineSID as string (corrected as per comment):**

```
string MachineSID = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])new 
DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0},Computer", 
Environment.MachineName)).Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().First().
InvokeGet("objectSID"),0).AccountDomainSid.Value.ToString();
```

you need to add a reference to System.DirectoryServices and make sure to have `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Security.Principal;` and `using System.DirectoryServices;`.

Comment: I think a user name/password/SID could be generated after some implementation of human interaction to allow the computer to be tagged as "admin". The downside would be more work for us to keep up with, but provided its a limited number of customers it shouldn't get out of hand.

Comment: see my edit for code get the machine ID - Windows creates this ID upon installation and keeps it unique...

Comment: Why is this giving me error when compiling? I cant get a clue as to whats happening. Could you come up with the correction? I see no `Cast` in intellisense for `Children`

Comment: @nawfal the above code uses extension methods/LINQ... which .NET version are you using ?

Comment: @Yahia thanks, it workds.. but here is an easier implementation of the same: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.AccountDomainSid.Value`

Comment: @Yahia is machineSID going to be the same if the windows version is pirated and installed on a second machine? Or is this value dependent on hardware components as well?

Comment: @nawfal that depends on the Windows version and the pirating mechanism used.

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially impossible to prevent people from "spoofing" a location. So plead with the clients to allow for a layer of authentication above the "location" they request.

Short of that you may want to take some loosely identifyable information such as the MAC, IP, or other specs and send it as an encrypted string. Anyone sniffing on the network wont be able to tell what the data being sent is so will have a harder time spoofing it if that is their goal. If they manage to decrypt the message then the data is in the open but until they're able to read it it provides a minor layer of security.

I still recommend against this idea but I'm sure it can be done. There is a truckload of issues you'd be forced to deal with that exist outside the software domain itself and would complicate things much more than a strong authentication scheme. Hopefully other members here can provide good examples to use but you don't want any false positives or otherwise (Dynamic IPs getting in the way etc.)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there is no good way to use the hardware as a *primary* means of authentication. You could do something like have an admin account that should be tied to certain hardware, and then try to heuristically detect changes in hardware but that's a scenario where you have an account AND hardware instead of an account OR hardware.

All preaching aside, if you can't convince the company that it's a bad idea, what I would do is provision those certain machines with keys that you authenticate with. Then you have full control over if/when to allow those keys to authenticate, you can revoke their access, but still give the effect of it being the *machine* that's authenticating, and not an account. It's still got all of the advantages and flexibility of being software controlled with the same effect of being hardware-based.